# Using checkboxes without a value attribute

Tags: html, forms

I Understand the ins and outs of forms, but say for example I have the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="urltoserver">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="1">Question</input>

</form>
```

Here I have set a value for the $_POST array. However, if I simply want to know if the checkbox is selected or not (ie im not bothered about the returned value), is it feasible/common practice to leave off the value attribute all together? Would it just return true/false in this case?

Comment: Side note, `<input>` tags are self-closing. And to answer your question, why don't you just try it?

Comment: note the 'common practice' in the question... some things are feasible in programming without necessarily being either correct or advised.

Comment: thought you might downvote for that, quite petty.

Comment: If your last comment was directed at me I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming PHP since you mentioned `$_POST`; correct me if I'm wrong.

if a checkbox is checked (and there is no value assigned) you should (IIRC) receive an `on` value back (as unchecked boxes aren't sent with the request). So, if you had:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" /> Foo
  <input type="checkbox" name="bar" checked="checked"/> Bar
  <input type="checkbox" name="baz" checked="checked"/> Baz
</form>
```

You'd see:

```
isset($_POST['foo']) == false
isset($_POST['bar']) == true
isset($_POST['baz']) == true
```

on the server-side when you went to read the check state.

the easiest thing to do though, if you're learning, is submit it to a page with the following code:

```
<?php
  var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

That will show you, verbatim, what was submitted (based on the form's populated values). From there you can play with how you want to format the form to receive the values you're expecting.